# The xxxx library may need to update its package.json or typings.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a public component library call `rd-component`, when I used this component `"rd-component": "^0.1.47"` in the new project, the visual studio code show error like this:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'rd-component'. '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/ppt-web/node_modules/.pnpm/rd-component@0.1.47_@types+node@20.1.1_react-dom@18.2.0_react-redux@8.0.5_react@18.2.0_vite@4.3.2/node_modules/rd-component/dist/rd-component.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/ppt-web/node_modules/rd-component/dist/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'rd-component' library may need to update its package.json or typings.ts(7016)
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the public rd-component's `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "rd-component",
    "version": "0.1.47",
    "type": "module",
    "description": "Reddwarf public component lib",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js"
        },
        "./dist/style.css": {
            "import": "./dist/style.css",
            "require": "./dist/style.css"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.1.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
        "antd": "^5.4.6",
        "vite-plugin-dts": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

I have already read some answers told that add typings, but it seems the legacy typescript configuration.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `types` field in `package.json` is no longer used if there is an [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) field: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#packagejson-exports-imports-and-self-referencing

> If you need to point to a different location for your type declarations, you can add a `"types"` import condition.

Therefore you should be good by simply copying your `"types": "./dist/index.d.ts"` indication within your `exports."."` declaration:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      // Specify types first
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": {
      "import": "./dist/style.css",
      "require": "./dist/style.css"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: you save my time.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!